# Unable to connect to mysql with pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python, pymysql

I'm trying to connect to mysql from pymysql with the following [example](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/example.py) script shared on their repo, but it keeps failing with the below message.

```
  File "/Users/svenkatesh/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 818, in _connect
    2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on %r (%s)" % (self.host, e))
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (255)")
```

Here's mysql user configuration, I tried both for **root** and **rv**,

```
mysql> select user, host, plugin from user;
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| user             | host      | plugin                |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| mysql.infoschema | localhost | mysql_native_password |
| mysql.session    | localhost | mysql_native_password |
| mysql.sys        | localhost | mysql_native_password |
| root             | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| rv               | localhost | mysql_native_password |
```

mysql service seems to be running fine on the required port as well.

```
C02WK0DQHV2J:Downloads svenkatesh$ sudo lsof -nPi -sTCP:LISTEN | grep sql
Password:
mysqld    15390         _mysql   19u  IPv6 0xf35d852c37f052c1      0t0  TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)
mysqld    15390         _mysql   22u  IPv6 0xf35d852c3792ce41      0t0  TCP *:33060 (LISTEN)

C02WK0DQHV2J:Downloads svenkatesh$ sudo netstat -an | grep -i sql
f35d852c413e4b61 stream      0      0 f35d852c463e3ca9                0                0                0 /tmp/mysqlx.sock
f35d852c413e65f1 stream      0      0 f35d852c44094009                0                0                0 /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Somethings changing `localhost` to `host='127.0.0.1'` does the trick. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yup already tried it with no luck :/

Comment: I uninstalled my current mysql version (5.7) and installed (5.5), it worked after that. Haven't figured out the issue with 5.7 though.